# Prevent NavBar showing

Tags: c#, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2013

I have a C# MVC application with a pretty-much standard Bootstrap display.

As usual the Navbar is provided by `Shared\_Layout.cshtml`.

However one of my pages will only be used for generating a PDF using an HTML/PDF converter, so I don't want the Navbar to appear.

Is there a way to prevent this for specific pages?

Comment: Is the pdf generated embedded inside a razor view?

Comment: Not within a view, probably in a class called from a controller and then sent as a download.

Comment: If this is sent as a download then the pdf file should not contain the navbar. The layout appears on Razor views not on the pdf.

Comment: The HTML source for the PDF is generated on my site, so it contains the Navbar

Comment: Actually I figured it out - I just need to add a querystring parameter e.g. "noheader" and check for that in the shared view

Answer (score 1):

I realised all I had to do was to add a querystring parameter that I can check for in `_Layout.cshtml`, i.e.:

```
<body>
    @if(Request.QueryString["noheader"] == null)
    {
    <div class="no-print navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                ...
```

Comment: ah so the actual page was converted. I misunderstood your question :D